# Using the project's name to access the home page

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, log4j, welcome-file

In my web application I have to write the URL of the web application and specify the `home.jsp` page that I want to be the home page, I want to know how I can access the the application in the browser just by typing the `project's root folder` name.

I have set the `welcome-file-list` in `web.xml` to the `home.jsp` that I want to get to every time I access the application, but it is not helping. Probably because I am using Struts 2 framework, If it is possible should I set the `welcome-file-list` in `struts.xml`?  How do I do it?

Another question, I have so far. For example in the `execute` method of one `action` class,
I want two different results `SUCCESS` or `ERROR`, as

```
if(message.getMessageBody() != null &&  
          message.getMessageDestinationEmail() != null &&
     message.getMessageHead() != null){
         return SUCCESS;
} else
     return ERROR;
```

I mapped the error to `error.jsp` page and success to a different `.jsp` page in `struts.xml` as

```
<action name="message" class="com.mule.basik.action.PostOfficeAction" 
                                                     method="execute">
        <result name="success">/status.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

But whether (in the browser form) I fill in the `messageHead` `messageBody` or not the `success` page (`/status.jsp`) is returned.

I am not sure how(when) struts2 instantiates the `objects` members of an `ActionClass`, so I decided to declare a `non parameter constructor` that instantiates the bean `message` (member of the action class) because I thought for every request an instance of the action class is created and thus there is a new instance of the `beans` the action class has (depends on). But it didn't help anything, what am I doing wrong? I guess I should try to use Log4j and print something in execute method before the `return SUCCESS` and before `return ERROR` to determine if the `if` statement is evaluating to `true` or `false`, but even if I find that it is evaluating to `true` when inputs are entered or not , I still don't understand what I will have to do next, to make the execute return `ERROR` beside testing as I showed above.

Comment: Answer to the second question: The problem about failing to return error, was being caused by the fact that the inputs, if not specified are empty by default; so I had to not only check if there are not null but also if there are not empty. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use a welcome file list, you should configure it in `web.xml` or web server default configuration file the files used as welcome files. When you access the web folder that contains this file the content of the the file will be loaded by web server regardless struts2 maps this folder or not as its action. Then in the welcome file you should place the code that redirect to the action. For example `index.jsp` is welcome file

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<% response.sendRedirect("showcase.action"); %>
```

Second question already discussed here, initializing the beans in the constructor is a bad idea, the constructor is used by the container to instantiate the action. At the moment when it's doing it you can't access some features or services because they are not available. Better do lazy initialization after the action is created and features are available, for example when the action is executed. If you want all actions to initialize before their execution than there's `Preparable` interface which is by default implemented by `ActionSupport` which you action should extend and override `prepare` method.

It's your responsibility to initialize the objects. Other objects that are submitted could be created by OGNL to populate your collections.

You could use Log4j with struts2 but it requires configuration in the project and on the server. For debug purposes you could write to the `System.out` which is redirected in the most IDEs to the console.

Really, I don't know what you are trying to do but normally return `SUCCESS` if no errors are found, or `ERROR` if there are errors.

Comment: The problem about failing to return error, was being caused by the fact that the inputs if not specified are `empty` `Strings` by default so I had to not only check if there are `not null` but also if there are not empty. I will be validating too, thanks for the TRICK

Comment: @user976095 The validation is better than manual checks, because it's free of bugs like yours, and it's an integral part of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `welcome-file-list` with struts also in your web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since second part of your question is answered above , so i will not go in to details, i will try suggest a solution for the first part.

Since you want everything to be handle by Struts2 when some one hit your URL, so in that case as it is required that we should follow/execute complete flow by action so that Framework should get option to initialize its internal structure.

Here is one way to do that.

you can always declare Struts2 action name in you `web.xml` file and i am assuming that your first action name is `welcome.action`, here is what we need to have in web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>welcome</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

1. Now create an empty `welcome` file inside your `web-app` folder.
2. Create your welcome action say `

In Last part you need to configure you Welcome action in `struts.xml` file or through annotation like.

```
<action name="welcome" class="welcomeAction">
   <result>welcome.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

You can define all you logic which you want to execute inside your `welcomeAction`.Please take care of these points

1. action name inside `struts.xml` file should be same as you have in welcome file list.
2. Don't forget to make a file with same name as your welcome action name in `web-app` folder as this is a trick to let container call you Action.

Hope this will help you and many others who have same issue.

`

Comment: Yes that is what I did actually. it was just not working, because of typo error, and the second question the inputs were retrieved `empty` not null, testing null was not the right thing to check. Thks though